# What is the equivalent ExpectedCondition of "Wait Until Page Contains" of robot framework in Java

Tags: java, selenium, robotframework, webdriverwait, selenium2library

I know there are types of wait in java

Implicit wait-

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Explicit wait-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, explicitWaitSec);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
```

Fluent wait-

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)                            
        .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)          
        .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)          
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

, but I am confused which of the waits and expected conditions will serve me closest to `Wait Until Page Contains` keyword in Robot Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct analog, that's a capability developed explicitly in in Robot Framework.
In the same time, you can achieve it with ExpectedCondition's [presenceOfElementLocated()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) with explicit/fluent wait (the latter is just more customizable version of the first, btw).

For a locator, use this xpath:

```
//*[contains(., "Your Text Here")]
```

This is what [Robotf Framework actually does](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/blob/master/src/SeleniumLibrary/base/context.py#L80), quite clever I must admit.

Comment: Thanks @Todor, can you please point(link/URL) where can look at inside robot frameworks method which implements this

Comment: Sure - https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary/blob/master/src/SeleniumLibrary/keywords/waiting.py#L99

Comment: @Dev updated the answer with some more details how to replicate; cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

### Wait Until Page Contains

[Wait Until Page Contains](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Wait%20Until%20Page%20Contains) is the implementation to *wait* for the `text` to appear within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). It is documented as:

```
Keyword                     Arguments                           Documentation
-------                     ---------                           -------------
Wait Until Page Contains    text, timeout=None, error=None      Waits until text appears on current page.
                                                                Fails if timeout expires before the text appears. See the Timeouts section for more information about using timeouts and their default value.
                                                                error can be used to override the default error message.
```

Source Code:

```
@keyword
def wait_until_page_contains(self, text, timeout=None, error=None):
    """Waits until ``text`` appears on current page.
    Fails if ``timeout`` expires before the text appears. See
    the `Timeouts` section for more information about using timeouts
    and their default value.
    ``error`` can be used to override the default error message.
    """
    self._wait_until(lambda: self.is_text_present(text),
                     "Text '%s' did not appear in <TIMEOUT>." % text,
                     timeout, error)
```

So the equivalent [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) can be either of the following:

- [`textToBePresentInElement(WebElement element, java.lang.String text)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#textToBePresentInElement-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-java.lang.String-): An expectation for checking if the given text is present in the specified element.
- [`textToBePresentInElementLocated(By locator, java.lang.String text)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#textToBePresentInElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-java.lang.String-): An expectation for checking if the given text is present in the element that matches the given locator.
- [`textToBePresentInElementValue(By locator, java.lang.String text)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#textToBePresentInElementValue-org.openqa.selenium.By-java.lang.String-): An expectation for checking if the given text is present in the specified elements value attribute.
- [`textToBePresentInElementValue(WebElement element, java.lang.String text)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#textToBePresentInElementValue-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-java.lang.String-): An expectation for checking if the given text is present in the specified elements value attribute.

**Note**: One significant difference is, while `wait_until_page_contains` is relative to the *current page* i.e. the current [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes), the `ExpectedConditions` are based on *WebElements* on the *current page* which makes your *Tests* much more granular.

Comment: Apart from repeating what is in the other answers - e.g. not bringing anything new to the table, the answer is incomplete/incorrect - the keyword `Wait Until Page Contains` does **not** use any locators, it looks in the full DOM for a string. All these keywords expect a specific locator, to first match an element and then check its text.

Comment: @DebanjanB thanks, For showing possible more options,  which can lined up after `presenceOfElementLocated()`  in list of possible solutions, +1

Comment: Hmm, the _usecase_ is still not _super clear_ to me. However my answer is based on the condition _Wait Until Page Contains_ which is exclusively based on the **text** and IMO _presenceOfElementLocated()_ isn't meant for this validation. Finally, everything boils down to what worked for you. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

There is like more functions like but this three use mostly..

`Wait Until Element Is Enabled` assumes that the element exists on the page, and will wait until the element is enabled (not readonly, and not disabled). If the element does not exist, it will fail immediately (or after a timeout if you have an implicit wait)

`Wait Until Element is Visible` assumes that the element exists on the page, and will wait until the element is visible. If the element does not exist, it will fail immediately (or after a timeout if you have an implicit wait)

`Wait Until Page Contains Element` makes no assumptions about the element. It waits until the element is actually on the page, regardless if it is visible, invisible, enabled, or disabled. It does not require an implicit wait, since this keyword is an explicit wait.

The most complete solution is to wait for it to be on the page, wait for it to be visible, and then wait for it to be enabled.

If the element will always be on the page, you can skip the first check (ie: if there's no `javascript` that can create or delete the element).

If the element will always be enabled, you don't need to wait for it to become enabled (ie: if there's no `javascript` to disable or enable the element)

For simple static pages, you really only need to check that an element is visible. Even that isn't usually necessary since selenium doesn't return from opening a page until the page is loaded. The problem comes when the page is dynamic. That is, when there is `javascript` that can change what is on the page and whether it is visible or enabled, after the html has loaded.

No, because "is loaded" can mean different things in different applications. The browser will set the variable `document.readyState` to "`complete`" when it's done loading the html. You can check for that in robot with something like Wait for condition  `return window.document.readyState === 'complete'`. Again, if you have `javascript` that runs on the page, this may not be sufficient since the page might change after the initial `HTML` is loaded.

Comment: The question is how to do `Wait Until Page Contains` in Java. This answer provides only Robot Framework alternatives and as such does not line up with what is asked.

Comment: The explanation is not entirely correct - `Wait Until Element Is *` will **not** fail immediately if the element is not present; on the contrary, they will first wait for the element to appear in the DOM, and then check on their specific condition.

Comment: @akshaypatil I was referring to these statements - "... assumes that the element exists on the page...". That's not so - if the element is not in the page, the keywords will not fail directly, they **will** wait for it to appear and then do the other verifications. Hopefully this makes it clearer.